# Is there a way to make the iPad stay in the App Store when you buy an app?

Tags: ipad, ios, ios-appstore

This has infuriated me since I got my iPad. If I am buying multiple Apps the iPad takes me to my Desktop after I buy each app, meaning I have to go back to the app store.

Is there a way to tell it to stay in the appstore when I buy an app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official way to do so, but if you've jailbroken your iPad, you can use [StayOpened](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/a-tweak-to-keep-the-appstore-open-after-you-download-an-app-stayopened/). It's a Cydia Tweak and I can highly recommend it. It does exactly what you want.